# Weird ordering of time with dplyr and lubridate

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I am trying to order time stamps with dplyr and lubridate but I'm not getting my expected ordering.

```
library(lubridate);library(dplyr)

foo <- data.frame(time = ymd_hms(c("2016-08-31 13:40:00", "2016-08-31 06:40:00", "2016-08-31 10:40:00")), 
                      expected_order = c(3,1,2)) 
foo %>% mutate(dplyr_ordered = order(time))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You confused what the `order` and `rank` do, from `?order`:

> order returns a permutation which rearranges its first argument into
>   ascending or descending order.

`order` does not return a rank of the actual value but an index vector which can be used to sort the vector, compare the following result:

```
foo %>% mutate(dplyr_order = order(time), dplyr_rank = rank(time))

#                  time expected_order dplyr_order dplyr_rank
# 1 2016-08-31 13:40:00              3           2          3
# 2 2016-08-31 06:40:00              1           3          1
# 3 2016-08-31 10:40:00              2           1          2
```

The result from `rank` is what you are expecting. The result from `order` tells you that the second element in time is smallest, followed by the third element and the first element is the largest.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing weird going on except that you're expecting the row numbers to be listed in `dplyr_ordered`.

```
foo$time
#> [1] "2016-08-31 13:40:00 UTC" "2016-08-31 06:40:00 UTC" "2016-08-31 10:40:00 UTC"

order(foo$time)
#> [1] 2 3 1
```

As expected, item `2` of `foo$time` is the first in order, then `3`, then `1`.

Comment: I would expect it to be 3,1,2

Comment: Look at `foo$time` as I've shown it. Read `order` as 'place the elements in order' not 'what rank should these elements be'.